# Parsing invalid JSON in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The log generated from API is in Invalid JSON format. something like this.

```
{"name": Power Amp,Component: Power Amplifier\n1/2 Inductor \n3 Power Capacitor\n Semiconductor\n Software\TV\n wafer\n Sony Dolby, \n \n L, pin, Or Amp"}
{name: Signal , Component: "1 make\n1 model, Halved \n1-1/2nd Rectifier\n Diode, to \n5 microwave\n8 henry\n8 ohm"}
```

Error: 
is there any in-built function in pySpark which allow us to handle this kind of scenario.

i am trying to Create  either RDD or DataFrame.

> Error: Parse error on line 1

How can we handle such corrupt JSON file in Pyspark?
 Kindly share your thoughts, if we can handle such scenario in pyspark

Comment: Do you want to ignore invalid json rows and read valid ones? Or parse invalid ones?

Comment: @Salim: which can be possible, if it possible to parse the invalid one i will go with that.... please help... Thanks

Comment: @Salim: I am using pyspark and not scala....Please help.

Comment: @Salim: Or How can we discard bad records.... please help

Comment: You can discard bad records in a couple of ways. Here is my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774527/discard-bad-record-and-load-only-good-records-to-dataframe-from-json-file-in-pys  Please upvote if it works for you. At least 1 good is needed to view the dataframe, then you can see both good and bad records. All bad records can be completely removed by using option ‘ignore malformed’

Answer (score 0):

It seems the query generate redundant rows. So you must use distinct() function to get distinct rows.

```
df.distinct().write.json('filepath.json');
```

Hope this helps.